# how to code to rearrange all text in a column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a column like this:

company_name
/Abcde/Tech
/abcde/tech-partner

and so on now i want to rearrange the whole columne by removing /abcde/,/Abcde/ so that only company name appears in column like:

Tech 
tech-partner
how to do this

Comment: Do you have a column? or a string?

Comment: a complete column with more then 60000 entries like the first entry is /abcde/Tech  2nd entry is /Abcde/tech-partner  and i want to remove /Abcde/ and  /abcde/ this parts so that in complete column only shows name like tevh then tech-partner and so on

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your input txt file looks like this:

> /abcde/Tech
>
> /Abcde/tech-partner

And you want the following output written to another txt file:

> Tech
>
> Tech-partner

Try the following code:

```
import re
filename = input("Enter file name: ")
with open (filename, 'r') as input_filename:
    with open ('output.txt','w') as output_filename:
        for line in input_filename:
            line = re.sub(r'\/Abcde\/|\/abcde\/',' ',line)
            output_filename.write(line)
    output_filename.close()
input_filename.close()
```

Your desired output will be in the txt file output.txt